# In dplyr how are objects passed to functions via the %>% pipe?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(55)

a <- c(100 %>% rnorm(10, mean = .))
b <- c(rnorm(100, 10, mean = 100))

identical(a, b)
[1] FALSE
```

I'm looking at the `a` variable. My understanding of a 'pipe' is that it passes the object to the left of the 'pipe' as the first parameter of the following function, and it also fills in any (.) with the object to the left of the pipe.

If that's true, my `b` variable would be equivalent to my `a` variable, but it's not. Why isn't the `100` being passed as the first parameter in `rnorm()` for my `a` variable?

Comment: Do `a` and `b` actually contain the same values? I notice that you don't reset the random seed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resetting the seed and making them into truly identical functions yields identical results.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(55)
a <- c(100 %>% rnorm(10, mean = 100))

set.seed(55)
b <- c(rnorm(100, 10, mean = 100))

identical(a, b)
[1] TRUE
```

The dot from the the `magrittr` package determines where to place the value passed from the pipe, it does not duplicate it.  So your first function generates only 10 examples instead of 100.

Comment: Oah wow, I thought `set.seed()` lasted the duration of your entire R session. Is it only used *once*, then has to be called again each time you use it? I guess so.

Comment: Not quite. The first time you set it you get the same 100 numbers, then you need to reset it to get those same 100 numbers. Otherwise you get the next 100 numbers in the pseudo random sequence.

Comment: Nice answer, @IanWesley. I just wanted to point out that it's possible to duplicate the left-hand side of the pipe using `.`; it just needs additional enclosure with parentheses: `a <- c(100 %>% rnorm(10, mean = (.)))`